# Which master is compared in a pull request?

Tags: github, branch, pull-request

I was looking at the changes in a pull request and found something strange. It appears as though the pull request compares my local version of master with my branch. How is that?

Screenshot of pull request on top and master branch at the bottom:

[image: Pull request on top and master branch at the bottom]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.
**At the top of every pull request, you can see which two branches are being compared.**

Look at this image, `new-exchange-bitbns` is the branch I'm trying to merge into `master` of forked repo.
[image]

Also, you should consider searching,there are many excellent guides out there to help you around github interface.

Comment: Hi and thanks. I know that I'm trying to merge into master but I'm wondering which version of master. It's apparently not origin which I found surprising.

Comment: what do you mean by which version of master ?